powershell autocomplete (ctrl + space) not working inside intellij internal terminal
I use powershell a lot and for me is convenient the powershell terminal inside intellij.
But the autocomplete (ctrl + space), is not working inside the intellij terminal.
I think it does not forward (ctrl + space) to the terminal. Every other comamand works perfect (ctrl+R, key up, etc).
Of course ctrl space completion works fine on powershell outside intellij.
Thanks in advance for any help.

It works fine on my side. Please attach screenshot from "File | Settings | Tools | Terminal"

Your comment made me think, I tried to reproduce the issue in a second notebook I have and I coudn't, same  Intellij version and same "File | Settings | Tools | Terminal". Still I have no idea what happend.
One workaround I found is to use
"Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Chord 'shift+Spacebar' -Function MenuComplete"
I added that to my $profile, so I don't have to type everytime.

You may try to run IDE with defaults ("File | Manage IDE settings | restore default settings" and check if it helps.
